# Inbox doesn't reflect comment edit

Tags: discussion, comments, edits, notifications, global-inbox

This might be a dupe but I couldn't find it, so I am posting it, taking a dreadful risk.

Alright, someone posts a comment on my post. It goes to my inbox. He then edits his comment, the inbox message doesn't reflect this change. It stays like that.

Noticed this here:

[image: message in inbox]

<sub>Original message is "*yes, completely! :D*"</sub>

[image: edited message, notice highlight]

<sub>After edit, it is this...</sub>

So, is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

Comment: Yup, asked almost four years ago. No harm done! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard hehe, new it would be a dupe... lol :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Edits are not reflected in inbox.